# google maps custom markers / shadow help needed

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

so I have google maps directions on my website, I have managed to change the icon, although I can't seem to get it to align it with the original marker shadow (which I actually need help removing also, it's just a good point to show that my custom marker is off). I hope this made sense?

The url is: http://www.emuholidaypark.com.au/location.html

As you'll see, there is a custom marker (not aligned properly) and the original shadow (which I can't seem to get rid of?)

The code is:

```
var gdir, fromAddress, toAddress;

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    //settings
    var companyMarkerImage = "/templates/home/images/mymarker.png";
    var companyLatLng      = new GLatLng(-37.056800, 142.329023);
    var companyMarkerSize  = new GSize(91, 53); //width, height
    toAddress = "Emu Holiday Park";
    var defaultZoomLevel  = 13;
    //end settings
    //setup elements
    map   = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    gdir  = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
    //error handler
    GEvent.addListener(gdir, "error", handleErrors);
    //set company marker
    var companyMarker = createMarker(companyLatLng, companyMarkerImage, companyMarkerSize);
    //set map center
    map.setCenter(companyLatLng, defaultZoomLevel);
    map.addOverlay(companyMarker);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
  }
}

function overlayDirections(){
  fromAddress =
    document.getElementById("street").value
    + " " + document.getElementById("city").value
    + " " + document.getElementById("state").options[document.getElementById("state").selectedIndex].value
    + " " + document.getElementById("zip").value;
    gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress
  );
}

function createMarker(latlng, imageURL, imageSize) {
  var marker = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON, imageURL);
  marker.iconSize = imageSize;
  return new GMarker(latlng, { icon: marker });
}

function handleErrors(){
  if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS)
    alert("No corresponding geographic location could be found for one of the specified addresses. This may be due to the fact that the address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect.\nError code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
  else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR)
    alert("A geocoding or directions request could not be successfully processed, yet the exact reason for the failure is not known.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
  else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_MISSING_QUERY)
    alert("The HTTP q parameter was either missing or had no value. For geocoder requests, this means that an empty address was specified as input. For directions requests, this means that no query was specified in the input.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
  else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_KEY)
    alert("The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given. \n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
  else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_REQUEST)
    alert("A directions request could not be successfully parsed.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
  else alert("An unknown error occurred.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createMarker(latlng, imageURL, imageSize) {
  var marker = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON, imageURL);
  marker.iconSize = imageSize;
  marker.shadow = null;
  return new GMarker(latlng, { icon: marker });
}
```

You'll also want to set iconSize if you're using a maker that isn't the same size as the standard one.